# how to addMarker from google sheet to google app script

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have two column in google sheet , that contain latitude and longitude,
i use below foramt:

```
var map=Maps.newStaticMap().setLanguage('en')
      .beginPath()
      .addMarker(lat, long)
      .addMarker(lat1, long1)
      .addMarker(lat2, long2)
      .addMarker(lat3, long3)
      .endPath().getAs('image/jpeg');
```

i want to add multi addmarker from reading google sheet,

i used this code in google script:

```
var app=SpreadsheetApp
var ss= app.openById("1dNw5loVnxpBysrYC9t49vc5LRkOytSP23Blo-ny_oM");
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
var lastRow2= sheet2.getLastRow();
var numRow=lastRow2-7;
var marker= "";
for (var i=8;i<=lastRow2;i++){
marker=marker+".addMarker("+sheet2.getRange(i,1).getValue()+","+ sheet2.getRange(i,2).getValue()+")";
}
marker=marker+".";

var map=Maps.newStaticMap().setLanguage('en').beginPath()+marker+endPath().getAs('image/jpeg');
```

marker output is this:

```
.addMarker(32.645814,51.669745).addMarker(32.646284,51.66835).addMarker(32.645769,51.665775).addMarker(32.645769,51.665775).addMarker(32.645769,51.665775).addMarker(32.645769,51.665775).addMarker(32.647468,51.665443).addMarker(32.650087,51.665625).addMarker(32.652779,51.665893).addMarker(32.653032,51.665389).addMarker(32.653032,51.665389).addMarker(32.653032,51.665389).addMarker(32.653032,51.665389).addMarker(32.653493,51.66599).addMarker(32.653899,51.664413).addMarker(32.654812,51.665571).addMarker(32.656347,51.665582).addMarker(32.656808,51.66202).addMarker(32.656916,51.660207).addMarker(32.660204,51.660572).addMarker(32.663049,51.661119).addMarker(32.663302,51.661666).addMarker(32.663302,51.661666).addMarker(32.663302,51.661666).
```

it work when i copy past marker output manuly in map variable:

```
var map=Maps.newStaticMap().setLanguage('en').setMarkerStyle(Maps.StaticMap.MarkerSize.TINY, Maps.StaticMap.Color.RED , '1').beginPath().addMarker(32.645814,51.669745).addMarker(32.646284,51.66835).addMarker(32.645769,51.665775).addMarker(32.645769,51.665775).addMarker(32.645769,51.665775).addMarker(32.645769,51.665775).addMarker(32.647468,51.665443).addMarker(32.650087,51.665625).addMarker(32.652779,51.665893).addMarker(32.653032,51.665389).addMarker(32.653032,51.665389).addMarker(32.653032,51.665389).addMarker(32.653032,51.665389).addMarker(32.653493,51.66599).addMarker(32.653899,51.664413).addMarker(32.654812,51.665571).addMarker(32.656347,51.665582).addMarker(32.656808,51.66202).addMarker(32.656916,51.660207).addMarker(32.660204,51.660572).addMarker(32.663049,51.661119).addMarker(32.663302,51.661666).addMarker(32.663302,51.661666).addMarker(32.663302,51.661666).endPath().getAs('image/jpeg');
```

bu it dont work when i use this form:

```
var map=Maps.newStaticMap().setLanguage('en').beginPath()+marker+endPath().getAs('image/jpeg');
```

[image of my google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWrRu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get a variable to work with map to add markers, however, you can loop through adding markers to map. This simple example adds all your latlong as markers. I don't know what you do with map. In my example I get the url and create a hyperlink returned to Sheet4 you can click to see the results.

```
function multiMarker() {
var map = Maps.newStaticMap()
       .setSize(600, 600)
       .setCenter('32.647468,51.665443');
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
var lr= s.getLastRow();
var rng=s.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, 2).getValues()
for (var i=0;i<=rng.length-1;i++){
    map.addMarker(rng[i][0],rng[i][1])
}
map.getAs('image/jpeg');
   var url=map.getMapUrl();
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet4').getRange("A1").setValue(url);
   var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('No Title');
   app.add(app.createImage(map.getMapUrl()));
    }
```

Comment: thank you ,Ed Nelson . but it return only string !!! and dont return image of map :(